# PHP Warning Message

Tags: php, mysqli

When I am running the script it is showing this error message:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp64\www\VehicleWorkshop\dbconnection.php on line 9

The code inside the dbconnection.php is as follow

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","technology");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

mysqli_select_db("eworkshop");
?>
```

Please help me resolving this problem.

Comment: Refer to syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqli_select_db()` function is used to select or change the default database for the connection.

**Syntax:**

```
mysqli_select_db(connection,dbname);
```

so try

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"eworkshop");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select your database in connection

Try this

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","technology", "eworkshop");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add connection as first param

```
mysqli_select_db($con, 'eworkshop') or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the PHP parser informs you the `mysqli_select_db()` function expects 2 parameters:

1) A mysqli object which holds the credentials to the database. This object is generated by `mysqli_connect()` function.

2) A string with the name of the database.

So the correct usage is `mysqli_select_db($con,"eworkshop");`

Hope it helps :)